# Выкопировка из плана или с плана

Tags: грамотная-речь

По профилю работы часто сталкиваюсь с такой фразой. Хотелось бы писать правильно. Выкопировка из плана меня смущает (из чего-то). А выкопировка с плана смущает других. Хотя мы ведь коприруем с бумажного источника (документа). Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Со ссылкой на источник

Answer (score 2):

Каждая из форм образуется под влиянием разных аналогий - поведения слов с похожими значениями. Если проследить эти аналогии, увидим, что форма "с плана" хуже, так как прототип меняется сильнее:

1) Смотрим синоним **копия**. Мы говорим: **копия картины** - вообще без предлога, аналогия требует здесь "выкопировки плана"; предлог можно притянуть только в процесс - **снять копию с картины** - "снять выкопировку с генплана".

2) Наиболее близкий синоним здесь, очевидно, **вырезка**. Мы говорим: **вырезка из газеты**, аналогия будет **выкопировка из генплана**.

3) Можно рассматривать *выкопировку* как **информацию** - что тоже требует предлога *из* (**информация из генплана**).

=== upd ===

4) Как нам подсказывает [[@Дерзкий](/users/1971/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)](/users/1971/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), есть более сильный синоним - **выдержка**, который так же требует предлога "из".

Comment: Спасибо. Третий пункт, возможно, применим к данной ситуации

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень представляю, что она из себя представляет, это выкопировека, равно, впрочем, как и сам план...
Но если одно часть другого, то предлог не нужен. Часть чего? - Плана. Выкопировка плана.
Если же это не часть плана, а какое-то извлечение из оного, то ИЗ плана.

Если план-чертеж, и с него (с его части) делается копия, то - С плана.

Comment: Кто пояснит мнение наимудрейшего?

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, behemothus

Answer (score 1):

Извините, а слово выкопировка Вас не смущает? Может, просто копия плана или части плана?

Comment: Нет, не смущает. Часть плана горных выработок называется именно так: "Выкопировка". Это было названо так в давние времена, когда о множительной технике не было и речи. Были работники, копировщики, которые именно вручную копировали информацию с (или из) планов горных выработок. С тех пор документ так и подписывают: "Выкопировка с (из) плана горных выработок по пласту..."

Comment: Как нам подскажет метранпаж, *выкопировка* - это скопированная *выдержка* из большого документа...